# collision with wall isn't accurate

Tags: android-studio

So I'm trying to make a ball hit the wall and bounce off it just like pong game. but for some reason when ball thinks the canvas is smaller that it actually is.
here is my onDraw code:

```
        canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
        canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
        if (flag) {
            x = (int) canvasWidth;
            y = (int) canvasHeight;
        }
    else
        {
            if (goingRight)
            x=x+5;
            else
            x=x-5;
            if (goingDown)
            y=y+5;
            else
                y=y-5;
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball,x/2,y/2,null);
        if (x>canvasWidth)
            goingRight=false;
        else if (x<0)
        goingRight=true;
    if (y>canvasHeight)
        goingDown=false;
    else if (y<0)
    {
        goingDown=true;
    }




    flag=false;
```

Couldn't find a fix for it. anyone knows what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you draw your ball at half x and half y.

```
canvas.drawBitmap(ball,x/2,y/2,null);
```

I think you want draw the ball not on top/left corner of the bitmap but  on center.

Is not tested ! Try somthing as...

```
canvas.drawBitmap(ball,x - (ball.getWidth()/2),y - (ball.getHeight()/2),null);
```